# Vectors in isotypic components

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory

Let $G$ be a finite group, and $\rho:G\to GL(V)$ a complex representation. Recall that for an irreducible character $\chi$, the $\chi$-isotypic component $V[\chi]$ is the image of the $\chi$-isotypic projector $$P_{\chi}:=\frac{\chi(1)}{|G|}\sum_{g\in G}\overline{\chi(g)}\rho(g),$$
and $V=\bigoplus_{\chi} V[\chi]$. $V[\chi]$ is characterized as the unique subrepresentation of $V$ such that every irreducible subrepresentation of it is isomorphic to the irreducible representation $W$ of $G$ with character $\chi$.

My question is whether the individual vectors $v\in V_{\chi}$ have interesting transformation properties (beyond the tautologous $P_{\chi}v=v$ or that the set of $\rho(g)v$ span a representation which non-canonically decomposes into copies of $W$)? When $\chi$ is degree $1$ then such a description exists since $V[\chi]$ is the $\chi$-eigenspace, so vectors in $V[\chi]$ satisfy $\rho(g)v=\chi(g)v$.

As a concrete example, let $S_4$ act on $\mathbb{C}[x,y,z,w]$ through its action on $\mathbb{C}^4$ by the permutation representation. The elements of the invariant set $\mathbb{C}[x,y,z,w]^{S_4}$ and the sign-isotypic component {$f(x,y,z,w):(g\cdot f)(x,y,z)=\chi_{sign}(g)f(x,y,z,w)$} have natural transformation properties, but what about the polynomials in the other 3 isotypic components?

Comment: The only "transformation property" you've mentioned is being a simultaneous eigenvector, corresponding  to 1D irreps. What "transformation properties" would you say vectors have if $V$ is itself a single irrep but not 1D, for example? (What I've learned from physicists, speaking to them as a mathematician, is that they tend to use "transforms as" to mean "generates a rep isomorphic to," but you appear to be saying this is insufficient.)